# Issue with google cloud ml installation on local

Tags: google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

I had followed the following instructions for setting up google-cloud-ml on LOCAL: MAC/LINUX

[google-cloud-ml setup](https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/how-tos/getting-set-up)

But I am getting the following errors while verifying the setup with this command

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/master/tools/check_environment.py | python
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 70, in 
>     File "/Users/pratyusha/miniconda2/envs/cloudml/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/ml/**init**.py", line 16, in 
>       from google.cloud.ml.dataflow._analyzer import AnalyzeModel
>     File "/Users/pratyusha/miniconda2/envs/cloudml/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/ml/dataflow/**init**.py", line 22, in 
>       from _ml_transforms import DeployVersion
>     File "/Users/pratyusha/miniconda2/envs/cloudml/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/ml/dataflow/_ml_transforms.py", line 24, in 
>       import _ml_functions as ml_func
>     File "/Users/pratyusha/miniconda2/envs/cloudml/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/ml/dataflow/_ml_functions.py", line 25, in 
>       from google.cloud.ml.io.coders import TrainingJobResult
>     File "/Users/pratyusha/miniconda2/envs/cloudml/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/ml/io/**init**.py", line 21, in 
>       from transforms import LoadFeatures
>     File "/Users/pratyusha/miniconda2/envs/cloudml/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/ml/io/transforms.py", line 23, in 
>       from google.cloud.ml.dataflow.io import tfrecordio
>     File "/Users/pratyusha/miniconda2/envs/cloudml/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/ml/dataflow/io/**init**.py", line 15, in 
>       import tfrecordio
>     File "/Users/pratyusha/miniconda2/envs/cloudml/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/ml/dataflow/io/tfrecordio.py", line 16, in 
>       _crc32c_fn = snappy._crc32c  # pylint: disable=protected-access
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_crc32c'

Looks like there is some issue with dataflow library of google cloud.

I tried upgrading the dataflow library with the following command

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

but now, another error. Following is the stacktrace:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 70, in 
>     File "/Users/pratyusha/miniconda2/envs/cloudml/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/ml/**init**.py", line 16, in 
>       from google.cloud.ml.dataflow._analyzer import AnalyzeModel
>     File "/Users/pratyusha/miniconda2/envs/cloudml/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/ml/dataflow/**init**.py", line 17, in 
>       from _analyzer import AnalyzeModel
>     File "/Users/pratyusha/miniconda2/envs/cloudml/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/ml/dataflow/_analyzer.py", line 19, in 
>       import apache_beam as beam
>     File "/Users/pratyusha/miniconda2/envs/cloudml/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/**init**.py", line 78, in 
>       from apache_beam import io
>     File "/Users/pratyusha/miniconda2/envs/cloudml/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/**init**.py", line 21, in 
>       from apache_beam.io.avroio import *
>     File "/Users/pratyusha/miniconda2/envs/cloudml/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/avroio.py", line 29, in 
>       from apache_beam.io import filebasedsource
>     File "/Users/pratyusha/miniconda2/envs/cloudml/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/filebasedsource.py", line 32, in 
>       from apache_beam.io import concat_source
>     File "/Users/pratyusha/miniconda2/envs/cloudml/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/concat_source.py", line 24, in 
>       from apache_beam.io import iobase
>     File "/Users/pratyusha/miniconda2/envs/cloudml/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/iobase.py", line 853, in 
>       from apache_beam.runners.dataflow.native_io.iobase import *
>     File "/Users/pratyusha/miniconda2/envs/cloudml/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/**init**.py", line 23, in 
>       from apache_beam.runners.dataflow_runner import DataflowRunner
>     File "/Users/pratyusha/miniconda2/envs/cloudml/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow_runner.py", line 32, in 
>       from apache_beam.internal import json_value
>     File "/Users/pratyusha/miniconda2/envs/cloudml/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/json_value.py", line 20, in 
>       from apitools.base.py import extra_types
>     File "/Users/pratyusha/miniconda2/envs/cloudml/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apitools/base/py/**init**.py", line 23, in 
>       from apitools.base.py.credentials_lib import *
>     File "/Users/pratyusha/miniconda2/envs/cloudml/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apitools/base/py/credentials_lib.py", line 50, in 
>       from oauth2client import locked_file

Comment: I tried installing in a new conda environment and it worked. I could have messed up one of the steps.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a different version of 'snappy' is expected.  Can you check which version of python-snappy you have installed?

You can do this by running:

```
pip freeze | grep python-snappy
```

It worked for me with version 0.5, which is the latest version.  If you have an earlier version, try running:

```
pip install --upgrade python-snappy
```

(using 'sudo' or '--user' as necessary.)